# GUI Text box scrollbar help

Tags: java, user-interface, scroll, scrollbar

1.
      JTextArea messages = new JTextArea(5, 30);
   2.
      JScrollPane scrollTextBox = new JScrollPane(messages, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED );
   3.
      Container window;
   4.
      ...
   5.
      messages.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,100));
   6.
      messages.setLineWrap(true);
   7.
      messages.add(scrollTextBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   8.
      window.add(messages);
   9.

10.
      I'm trying to write a text box within a GUI box that returns messages from a server, it needs a scroll bar because messages are continually being sent but at the moment only the first few lines are visible and the rest aren't because i can't get the scroll to work.
  11.
      my attempts before have either resulted in this error:
  12.
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
  13.
              at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Unknown Source)
  14.
              at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
  15.
              at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
  16.
              at LODGUI.drawAndShow(LODGUI.java:91)
  17.
              at LODClient.run(LODClient.java:94)
  18.
              at LODClient.main(LODClient.java:157)
  19.

20.
      or no change and no scroll bar.

Comment: Here is a suggestion : use formatting rules from Markdown version of StackOverflow (visible when you edit your text) and we may have a chance to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained in the error message. You are adding *messages* to *scrollTextBox*, then adding *scrollTextBox* to *messages*.

And please please try to format you question...

Answer (score 0):

Delete line 7.

Change line 8 to:

```
window.add(scrollTextBox);
```

---

(The way to do it is to insert your component 'messages' into a JScrollPane which you do in line 2. Then, don't insert 'messages' into the container, but insert the scoll pane.)

And please, next time format your question.

Comment: thanks, i sorted it out in the end.
sorry bout the formatting, first time using this site and i'm just finding my way around.